# questions about comparing dates with date.time (not timedelta)

Tags: python-datetime

I am working on a text based RPG. I thought it would be nice to add some special events like Christmas items in the shop, or flavor text 'The town has a soft dusting of newly fallen snow.' I have attempted several ways but none of them seem to work. Any advice would really be appreciated. I tried using the official python document from  [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

```
import time
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
dateN=now.strftime('%m-%d')
print(dateN)
if dateN == (0o04,28):
    print("today")
elif dateN==(12,24):
    Christmas()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can compare the datetime objects directly (as opposed to comparing them in string form). Then to know if it's a holiday just check that the day and month are the same for both objects.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = datetime.datetime(day=29, month=4, year=2022)
christmas = datetime.datetime(day=24, month=12, year=2022)
now.month == today.month and now.day == today.day
Out[23]: True
now.month == christmas.month and now.day == christmas.day
Out[24]: False
```